# PHP-FPM ERROR: [/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:xxx] unknown entry 'process_control_timeout'

Tags: php-fpm

I have a LAMP stack with Amazon Linux 2, Apache 2.4, and PHP-FPM for PHP 8.1 and I'm trying to set the value for `process_control_timeout` in my PHP-FPM config

I added `process_control_timeout=50s` to the bottom of the file `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` but on reloading PHP-FPM it fails and the status contains the error

```
ERROR: [/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:xxx] unknown entry 'process_control_timeout'
```

According to the [PHP-FPM docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php), `process_control_timeout` is a valid option, and the mentioned config file `/etc/php-fpm.conf` includes `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

How do I set this value correctly?

Comment: Please add your config file. `process_control_timeout` is a global option and probably in the wrong section.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks! You are correct, I have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @GeraldSchneider in a comment, `process_control_timeout` is a global option and belongs under the `[global]` section

The `[global]` section was already defined in my `/etc/php-fpm.conf` file and adding `process_control_timeout=50s` there works as expected

By adding it to the bottom of `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` I was inadvertently adding it to the pool definition for `[www]`, which is what caused the error